# Display sum of values and group by another column within a column chart in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Lets say I have this table for instance, which shows the values and what colour it is for July 1st 2020:

[image]

Currently the column chart looks like so:

[image]

Is there a way to sum up `val` and group by the `RAG` column and represent this as a column chart?

So it will still show one chart but it will segment it into how much of that total was in the red zone, how much was in the amber zone and how much was in the green zone.

*Note*: I have tried adding RAG on the axis but this splits the chart rather I need them to be in one bar but showing the split between each RAG

[image]

Comment: Add RAG to the visual either as an Axis value or in the Legend

Comment: I've added RAG as the axis, however, this splits the chart. What I wanted to know if it was actually possible to stack them on top of each other in order to see the total value split up by the RAG in one single bar chart

Comment: Make sure you are using the stacked column and not the clustered column chart.  Add RAG as the Legend value

Comment: Ah! That's it, I was using the wrong visual - 100% Stacked Column Chart is what I was looking for. You should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Stacked Bar Chart visual and put RAG in as the legend.